# Azure Functions scalability issue

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Functions on the App Service Plan. My understanding is for every new execution the Azure Function will create a new App Service, execute the function and then shut down the App Service. There would be nothing shared between the multiple App Services that are spawned due to multiple requests.

However when I do test my Function(which is a video processing one), for one request the time it takes is around 2-3 mins however for multiple simultaneous requests the time increases to 10-15 mins. My questions are whether my understanding above is correct? If not then what resource is shared amongst these App Services? How should I decide my scaling options(manual vs auto)?

Comment: If you host Azure Function App to dedicated app service plan and production tier (example P1V2) , that has the Auto Scale features upto 20 instance, but subject to availability.  my suggestion is go for Premium Plan that will Automatically scales based on demand using pre-warmed workers which run applications with no delay after being idle, runs on more powerful instances, and connects to virtual networks.

Comment: Hey mate, if answers help please up vote or accept answers ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"My understanding is for every new execution the Azure Function will create a new App Service" Nope it will not run new instance each time. Generally if there is no load on AF it will stop all instances.

Then if first request/event comes in it will start first instance. This is why we have ColdStart in Serverless. After that scale controller  will measure your instance performance memory and CPU consumption and decide if it needs to scale but it wont be instant. So if lets say you sent N amount of requests to do smth with video they could go to same first instance and increase load. Then AF will scale, because of CPU spike but it wont help with old requests since they are handled at first instance. Keep in mind For non-HTTP triggers, new instances are allocated, at most, once every 30 seconds which means that your AF should have CPU spike for at least 30 second to add new instance https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/event-driven-scaling

I am not sure if Azure Functions are good option for video processing. Azure function should be used for quick stuff usually I would say not more than 30 sec. But there are some limitation of execution time depends how you run it https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan?tabs=portal

Not sure what type of video processing you doing but i would have a look into Azure Media Services

The other options as you mentioned is Batch jobs with low priority https://azure.microsoft.com/en-au/blog/announcing-public-preview-of-azure-batch-low-priority-vms/ it actually a good use case you have: Media processing and transcoding, rendering and so on

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I am actually running some custom FFMPEG scripts to would need to ability to process/mix video and audio with my script. I will take a look at Azure Media Services too. Would you suggest to use https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/batch/?

Comment: Thanks buddy for the clarification, we did move to Batch and it seems to be a good solution for now.

Answer (score 2):

A small addition to [Vova's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71221617/1945525): if you're running your Function in an App Service (also known as a [Dedicated Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dedicated-plan)), it will by default only scale instances within the possibilities of the App Service Plan you defined. This means that all of the instances of your Function App run on the same virtual machine. That is most probably the reason you're seeing increasing request times with more requests.
If you want your Functions to scale beyond the capabilities of that plan, you will need to manually scale or enable autoscaling for the App Service plan.

> An App Service plan defines a set of compute resources for an app to run. These compute resources are analogous to the server farm in conventional hosting.

and

> Using an App Service plan, you can manually scale out by adding more VM instances. You can also enable autoscale, though autoscale will be slower than the elastic scale of the Premium plan. [...] You can also scale up by choosing a different App Service plan.

If you run your Function App on [Consumption Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/consumption-plan) (the *true* serverless hosting plan option since it enables scaling to zero),

> The Consumption plan scales automatically, even during periods of high load.

In case you need longer execution times than those available in Consumption Plan, but the App Service Plan doesn't seem to be the best hosting environment for your Functions there's also the [Premium Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-premium-plan).

> The Azure Functions Elastic Premium plan is a dynamic scale hosting option for function apps.
>
> Premium plan hosting provides the following benefits to your functions:
>
> - Avoid cold starts with perpetually warm instances
> - Virtual network connectivity.
> - Unlimited execution duration, with 60 minutes guaranteed.
> - Premium instance sizes: one core, two core, and four core instances.
> - More predictable pricing, compared with the Consumption plan.
> - High-density app allocation for plans with multiple function apps.

More info on all the different [Azure Functions hosting options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scale).

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. We tried using Premium Azure Functions but the price is very high and just not affordable. For now we have moved to Batch, it turned out to be an affordable and scalable solution. Lets see once we move to production :)

Comment: So, what did you end up using for production usage?